# I want to create a function that will get a list of Key Vaults that don't have any virtual networks

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

The script parts work solo, but when run together generate the wrong output (i.e. shows KeyVaults that do have virtual networks. How do I fix this?

```
 function Get-KeyVault {

 [CmdletBinding()]

param (

    #Enter the path you would like to save the excel output  
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $Path         
    )

 $KeyVaults= Get-AzKeyVault
 $result=@()  

  foreach($keyvault in $KeyVaults)
 {
     $NetworkAcls=(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyvault).NetworkAcls
     $VirtualNetworkResourceIds= $NetworkAcls.VirtualNetworkResourceIds
     if ($VirtualNetworkResourceIds -eq $null)
         {
          $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
         Name= $keyvault.VaultName
         ResourceGroup= $keyvault.ResourceGroupName
         Location= $keyvault.Location
         }
   $result += $obj
        }
     }
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @iRon, I tried that. It doesn't change the output though.

Comment: Is it returning an empty IList object? Should you try `if ($VirtualNetworkResourceIds.Count -eq 0)` ? I would think that iRon's suggestion would account for that, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It returns an output, but includes those that have virtual networks as well. I tried the -eq 0 and that gives a blank output.

Comment: Perhaps you should output `$VirtualNetworkResourceIds` to screen, so you can see exactly what you're validating against.

Comment: Hmm yes I've tried that to ensure what is being validated, as well as in the portal itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Your code seems to be fine except for the below part :***

```
$NetworkAcls=(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyvault).NetworkAcls
```

Here in the `-VaultName` you are declaring ***$keyvault*** which is ***a object from the list of keyvaults not the keyvault name*** , for which the `$NetworkACLs` and `$VirtualNetworkResourceIds` ***doesn't provide any output and the if statement gets nullified resulting in storing all the keyvault names , their resourcegroup names and locations in the custom object***.

***To Fix that you will have to use the below so that the correct output is stored in the `NetworkAcls` variable and the next steps :***

```
$NetworkAcls=(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyvault.VaultName).NetworkAcls
```

**Complete code :**

```
function Get-KeyVault {

 [CmdletBinding()]

param (

    #Enter the path you would like to save the excel output  
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $Path         
    )

 $KeyVaults= Get-AzKeyVault
 $result=@()  

  foreach($keyvault in $KeyVaults)
 {
     $NetworkAcls=(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyvault.VaultName).NetworkAcls
     $VirtualNetworkResourceIds= $NetworkAcls.VirtualNetworkResourceIds
     if ($VirtualNetworkResourceIds -eq $Null)
         {
          $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
         Name= $keyvault.VaultName
         ResourceGroup= $keyvault.ResourceGroupName
         Location= $keyvault.Location
         }
   $result += $obj

        }
     }
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
 }
```

**I tested the same in my environment as well as below :**

***KV with Network Policy:***

[image]

**Issue output :**

[image]

**After applying fix :**

[image]